# Automatic quit of a python program in interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit, python-interactive

I'm writing a python (v. 3.9) program intended to be run in interactive mode. Program needs an argument to run properly. So, I try to check if the argument is present or if it is not in order to continue with the following lines:

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    prefix=sys.argv[1]
else : 
    print(" Usage: python -i my_program.py one_argument")
    quit()
```

But it just shows an error message and does not exit. I have tried also
`exit()`
`sys.exit()` `type(quit())` (in place of `quit()`) with the same result.

Is it possible to program in advance quitting in interactive mode?

Comment: Instead of requiring the user to use a certain flag, you can start the REPL yourself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.interact